# Why this sed command fails to capture the pattern?

Tags: sed, osx

I want to put a pair of parenthesis around a string using a `sed` oneliner.

This is what I have tried

```
echo 1 | sed -e 's/.*/(\0)/'
```

I expect the letter `1` will be matched by the `.*` pattern.

However the output is just

```
(0)
```

I actually wants to get this outcome:

```
(1)
```

I am using BSD `sed` on OSX

Comment: `echo 1 | sed 's/.*/\(\0\)/' ` should work.

Comment: Thanks, but nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: In my ubuntu it works. might be difference between distrobutions.

Comment: GNU sed on ubuntu  vs  BSD on OSX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is the standard way to substitute the whole pattern match. Some `sed` implementations like GNU's or busybox' support `\0` as an alternative but that's not standard nor portable.

```
$ echo 1 | sed -e 's/.*/(&)/'
(1)
```

That command encloses the first (possibly empty) sequence of *characters*, as many as possible in each line inside parenthesis. That may not enclose the  full line for those lines that contain bytes not forming valid characters, in which case you may find that:

```
sed 's/^/(/; s/$/)/'
```

Works more reliably to enclose the full *line* inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

`\1` would reference the first capturing group. As you currently don't have any capturing group, you can define the match as capturing group by surrounding it with braces and reference it using `\1`:

```
$ echo 1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/(\1)/'
(1)
```

Comment: No, `\0` is a literal zero. `\1` references the first capture group. Also, why did you add the `g` at the end (`.*` matches the whole line)?

Comment: Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: @Kusalananda, `.*` can match several times if the input contains bytes that don't form valid characters. For  instance with GNU `sed` in a UTF-8 locale, `printf 'a\200b\n' | sed 's/.*/(&)/g'` would output `(a)<0x80>(b)` while without `g`, it would output `(a)<0x80>b`. That `<0x80>` is not matched by `.` as it's not a character. YMMV as the behaviour of `sed` is unspecified for non-text input

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Would the file even be considered valid input to `sed` in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below awk command

```
echo 1 | awk '{print "("$0")"}'
```

output

```
(1)
```